# Chrome suddenly copying images in BLOB format

Tags: google-chrome, google-docs, copy-paste

I just noticed on Chrome 112 whenever I copy from Google Docs using Chrome browser, the images get copied as BLOB (Base64) instead of as images referencing the image uploaded to Google (they get uploaded to googleusercontent.com)

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABa...
```

This means that right now I'm unable to do things that I was able to do before.

For example, copy and paste text & images into Notion.
Now Notion will throw an error because it can't paste the image.

I noticed that this won't happen if I load Google Docs from another web browser such as Safari or Firefox, where in this case pasting to Notion (or any other rich editor) would look like this:

```html
<img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/LrtT2WDav4cXI....." referrerpolicy="same-origin" style="display: block; object-fit: cover; border-radius: 1px; pointer-events: auto; width: 100%;">
```

The problem persists using other Chrome accounts or even on the incognito window.

### The problem does not occur on Chrome < 112

Using Chhrome Version 112.0.5615.121 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: Have you tried to post the question inside [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) to see if there is a change in the Chrome Browser that is affecting the behavior of copy and paste. Or in the Git logs for updates [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/112.0.5615.100..112.0.5615.136?pretty=fuller&n=10000).

Comment: Same results in Firefox, edge to me(base64 blob image). Which OS did you try?

Comment: Yeah, now I'm also getting the same in other web browsers. It might be a change in Google Docs?